# {NiceTabular} word wrap issue

Tags: tables, color, colortbl, nicematrix

I'm using NiceTabular from the NiceMatrix package and I'm having trouble with wrapping text within a cell. I've found that I've gotten the best results from background color using this package because it doesn't seem to mess with the borders when rendering. However, if the text is too long it does not wrap around like it does with tabular. I'm fairly new, but it seems to me that if using just tabular, text will only wrap when you specify column width, but even with specifying column width in NiceTabular, it does not have the same effect.

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{|WC{0.5\textwidth}|WL{0.5\textwidth}|}[code-before = \rowcolor{gray!30}{1}]
\hline
\textbf{Level 1} & \textbf{Level 2}\\   
blah blah blah & long long line of blah blah that will not wrap when the table fills the column width\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
```

Yields:

[image]

I've read through the documentation and found nothing that helped, and this seems to be a fairly new package that I can't find many results on the internet (at least related to this issue). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two custom column types you can allow automatic linebreaks inside of the table cell. I have also altered the column width calculation in order to make sure the table fits into the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|Y{0.5}|P{0.5}|}[code-before = \rowcolor{gray!30}{1}]
\hline
\textbf{Level 1} & \textbf{Level 2}\\   
blah blah blah & long long line of blah blah that will not wrap when the table fills the column width\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works wonderfully! Still new to LateX so I wasn't aware of \newcolumntype. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The latest version de `nicematrix` (v. 6.0 of 2021-08-10) provides `X` columns similar of the columns of `tabularx` (with, in fact, optional keys as in `tabu`---obsolete---and `tabularray`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]X[l]}[vlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!30}{1}
\Body
  \Hline
  \RowStyle{\bfseries}
  Level 1 & Level 2\\   
  blah blah blah & long long line of blah blah that will not wrap when the table fills the column width\\
  \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Very nice!(+1). How to simple increase vertical space above/below cells contents (beside use of the `arraystretch`)?

Comment: @Zarko: `nicematrix` provides two parameters `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` similar to `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` of `cellspace`.

Comment: Thank you very much! As I already mentioned once, development of this interesting package is faster than my learning of it :-)

Comment: Fantastic!!! Truely nice package.